# Can I have different menu for each tab of TabHost

Tags: android

Is that possible to have different `menus` for each `tab` of `TabHost`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can in `onCreateOptionsMenu` depending on the tab inflate a different menu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   int tab = getTabHost().getCurrentTab()
   if (tab==1)
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu); 
   else
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.other_menu, menu); 
   return true;
}
```

You need to provide different versions of menu.xml files within `res/menu` for this.

Comment: That will not work. You will get one same menu for all tabs anyway (menu for current tab then will be shown for each tab). You need to use `onPrepareOptionsMenu` instead of `onCreateOptionsMenu` and call `menu.clear()` each time before inflating menus.

Comment: menu.clear() actually made my optionsmenues not appear at all. 
Instead i used getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

Answer (score 1):

If you're using fragments you can put `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` inside `onCreate` method of your fragment and override `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_xxx, menu);
}
```