# Menu different for each tab

Tags: android, menu, android-tabhost

I read that it was possible to display a different menu for each tab on this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618803/can-i-have-different-menu-for-each-tab-of-tabhost).

I have 3 tabs initialized in MainActivity.
Even if I call `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` or `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in each included `Activity`, they are never executed.
I just succeed in displaying a menu on MainActivity's initialization...

MainActivity:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_tab_1, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This menu is shown.
One of my TabActivities:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_tab_2, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This menu is not refreshed when I change the tab.
But I tried multiple combinations (onCreate / onPrepare, Override...) without success.

How do it properly?
Thanks

Comment: you sure you have written `@Override` tag. If so, kindly post your `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` & `onCreateOptionsMenu()`...

Comment: you can use a flag (for example an int) to keep track of which tab you're actually in.. then in onCreateOptionsMenu() you define your menu based on on the value of the flag.

Comment: Even if I use `@Override` it doesn't work. I put my code sorry

Comment: Anduriel, could you also post the XML for your menus?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do this.

First, you can override the onKeyDown method, and detect when the user presses the menu, and instead of letting the main activity handle it, dispatch the event to the active tab activity.

Else, you can use Fragments instead of activities inside your Tab host. The fragment mechanism is great to combine the Options Menus from multiple source (usually one activity and one or more fragments).