# How to change action bar on change of tab?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am developing an application in which i m having four tabs.I want that on click of each tab,action bar should change.Right now I have given action bar title,search bar and overflow icon.But I want to change action bar on selection of each tab so that I can add icon in action bar according to requirement on selection of corresponding tab.

Here is my code of ontabselection,please suggest what can I do.Any help is acceptable.

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            FragmentTransaction fragMentTra;
            if (tab.getText().equals("DEALS")) {
                try {
                    rl.removeAllViews();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
                actionBar.show();
                actionBar.setTitle("Deals");

                FragmentDeals Fram1 = new FragmentDeals();
                //fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
                fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), Fram1);
                fragMentTra.commit();
            }
            else if (tab.getText().equals("ORDER")) {
                try {
                    rl.removeAllViews();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
                actionBar.show();
                actionBar.setTitle("Order");
                FragmentOrder Fram2 = new FragmentOrder();
                //fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
                fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), Fram2);
                fragMentTra.commit();
            }

            else if(tab.getText().equals("CART")){
                try {
                    rl.removeAllViews();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
                actionBar.show();
                actionBar.setTitle("Shopping Cart");
                FragmentCart fram3 = new FragmentCart();
                //fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
                fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram3);
                fragMentTra.commit();
            }



            else if(tab.getText().equals("HISTORY")){
                try {
                    rl.removeAllViews();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
                actionBar.show();
                actionBar.setTitle("History");
                FragmentHistory fram4 = new FragmentHistory();
                //fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
                fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram4);
                fragMentTra.commit();
            }

        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want to add menu item for each tab right?

Comment: yes you are right.I want to add menu item.

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using fragments to do your tabs. QUite easily you can declare a menu.xml file for each fragment. Using sethasOptionmenu(true) in the oncreate of your fragment. Then you can adjust stuff if needed in onCreate Option menu().

Edit : here an example :

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}
@Override 
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu, android.view.MenuInflater inflater) {
    if (!hideOptionsMenu) {
        Log.e(TAG, " - onCreateOPTIONMenu");        
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.booking_accepted, menu);
        MenuItem cancel  = menu.findItem(R.id.cancel_booking_accepted);
        cancel.getIcon().setAlpha(Constants.ENABLED_OPACITY);
        menu.findItem(R.id.my_trips_switch).getIcon().setAlpha(Constants.ENABLED_OPACITY);
    }
    // (optional) reference to a OnItemSelectedListener, that you can use to perform actions based on user selection
}
```

Comment: we have to make ActionBarActivity?

Comment: Ah. ActionBarActivity is here for compatibility purpose. You have to decide untill wich version you want to be backward compatble.

Comment: yes. All I am saying is not certified to be corrected, i am a beginner like you. But as far as I understand : 
The actionbar is a built in component to which you can add menu item. the action bar will pull these item (buttons) from xml files. You can declare a file for the activity. You can also declare a file for a fragment. So, when a fragment is set as the one displayed (ex: viewpager), android will call the menu for the activity and then for the fragment. Typically, log out and settings are declared for the activity (so always there) but each fragment can have their action menu (print send

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to Poutrathor, but clearer for me. I got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15218201/1887635

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_xxx, menu);
}
```