# Change Menu when Tab changed in Android

Tags: android, menu, tabs, listener

I have two tabs in my application and I want the menu to change depending on the Tab.

Here what I did

```
  TabHost tabHost = tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
    photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.photo));
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, Photos.class);
    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);



    TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");       
    songspec.setIndicator("Songs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.songs));
    Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, Songs.class);
    songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
    tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
```

Now When the user clicks on the photos tab, I would like to display a menu for editing pictures and when the user clicks on songs tab I want to display a menu of controlling the order of the songs. I want to do this each time the user click on any of the tabs.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int currentTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
    if (currentTab == 0)
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Photosoptions.class));
    if (currentTab == 1)
        {
           startActivity(new Intent(this, Songsoptions.class));
                      } 
            return true;
        }



      @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        int currentTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();

        if (currentTab == 0){
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
           closeOptionsMenu();

           }
       if (currentTab ==1){
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        closeOptionsMenu();

       }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: I think this is duplicate with question like : [Can I have different menu for each tab of TabHost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618803/can-i-have-different-menu-for-each-tab-of-tabhost).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use following code:

```
@Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        int currentTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentTab+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        menu.clear();
        if (currentTab == 0) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.first, menu);  //  menu for photospec.
        } else {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.second, menu);  // menu for songspec
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

you don't needed **onCreateOptionsMenu** and you must handle item click with `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: But how I perform the action on each item? I mean I have been using `onCreateOptionsMenu` to provide the menu xml file and `onOptionsItemSelected` to perform the action when an item is selected should I use `onOptionsItemSelected` in the same way?

Comment: no you don't need `onCreateOptionsMenu` and you must handled clicked item with `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: Thanks, another question when I switch from tab 2 to tab 1, the old menu stays there until I press on the menu then it get updated. Is there a way to make sure it get updated the moment the user clicks on it?

Comment: you can call `closeOptionsMenu();` to ensure your menu is closed

Comment: I tried that and it still shows the old menu unless I click on it, then it change it

Comment: did you use `closeOptionsMenu();`? where you use that?

Comment: on `onPrepareOptionsMenu` after `inflater.inflate(R.menu.first, menu);`

Comment: you must use in `TabChanged`, when you want change tab call this method, if you call in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` its do nothing for you

Comment: So if I used `TabChanged` How am I going to be able to perform different action when the user chose an item. Just to be clear, I have two menus one for each tab, inside each menu I have different options, for example for photos I have menu1, it includes `rotate image`, `change color`, etc when the user press on option `rotate image` I would like to call a function that will do so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45192/discussion-between-shayan-pourvatan-and-lily)

Comment: are you sure @Lily? did you add tabChangeListener and in that nothing happened ? can you update your post with this function?

Comment: @Lily post new answer with your problem, because this answer is about changing menu in tab, but your problem now is something else,that i just know that, if you ask new question with your new problem all users can helped you,

Comment: You must call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` when you are using `OnTabSelectedListener`, because `invalidateOptionsMenu();` triggers `onPrepareOptionsMenu` every time you select different tab

Comment: @uuzelac yes, you are right, your answer is right too but my answer is right. thanks for mention