# Change ActionBar icons in each tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, icons, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I want to ask, if is there some way, how to set **different menu icons** in `ActionBar` **in different tabs**. For example, if the user is in tab number one, in the `ActionBar` would appear search icon and if the user is in tab number one, there would appear refresh icon.

Is there some way, how to do that? (I am using `ActionBar Fragment Navigaton Tabs`)

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Are you looking for viewpager indicator for your viewpager?

Comment: What do you mean by viewpager indicator?

Comment: Check whether you are looking for https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator  or you just want to change the action bar icon

Comment: do your job in `onTabSelected`, work with `tab.getPosition()`

Comment: @playmaker420 thanks for recommendation. But i am looking for icons in actionbar, not tabs. But this looks very interesting, i will take a look at it anyways! Shayan pourvatan: so i have to put there onCreateOpitonsMenu or how do you mean it?

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112145/change-menu-when-tab-changed-in-android/21112224#21112224

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in  `onTabSelected` method, which would call back `onPrepareOptionsMenu` . You can write menu hiding logic inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu` as like following.

```
/**
     * Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu()
     */
    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        try {
            if(tab 1 selected){
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setVisible(false);
                }
                else if(tab 2 selected){
                    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setVisible(true);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer, anyways, where should I put onPrepareOptionsMenu method?

Comment: @marson you can add it under tabListener onTabSelected event