# How to add Overflow menu at right end in Tabs in Android Phone

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-appcompat

I am making an android application where I need to create two `Tabs` that is simple I did but I need to add the OverFlow menu also in same row. See screenshot.

I never implement this in Android that might seems more tricky to me.

Please help me if you know how to achieve this in Android.

I simply achieved the `Tabs` using below code.

```
public class PayStubActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); // requesting to set the custom title bar
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_stub);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);

        // adding action bar tabs to the activity
        ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        Tab firstTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.paystub_current_tab)).setTabListener(this);
        Tab secondTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.paystub_all_tab)).setTabListener(this);

        // add the tabs to the action bar
        mActionBar.addTab(firstTab);
        mActionBar.addTab(secondTab);

        // set the navigation mode the Action Bar Tabs
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // user is selected first tab
        if(tab.getPosition() == 0) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new CurrentPayStubFragment());
        } else {
            // user is selected second tab.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}

}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this you want? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112145/change-menu-when-tab-changed-in-android/21112224#21112224)

Comment: @shayanpourvatan see screenshot. I want to add "Overflow" icon at the right end of two `ActionBar` Tabs. Any help ?

Comment: As you told it adds the "Overflow" menu in the `ActionBar` not in the Tabs. I want "Overflow" menu at the right end of the Tabs

Comment: And what it is doing now when you add items to menu in onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: @Billda It adds the "Overflow" menu in the `ActionBar` not in the Tab

Comment: I dont get it .. you mean that it creates classical action bar with overflow and tabs are below that? If it is so, i dont see any other solution than custom view with some library that create tabs (ViewPagerIndicator) and button for overflow menu

Comment: @Billda Yes I meant same but how this can be achieve.

Comment: What you want can be found in this [answer:][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604972/how-to-put-tabs-on-the-actionbar-same-level-with-up-button-and-menus/24605199#24605199

Comment: @Tinashe Can you please write that answer to this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a custom Layout for your Action bar:

layout_action_bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="@drawable/action_bar_divider"
    android:dividerPadding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="imagesViewClick">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="IMAGES"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/images_selected_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#427fed"/>
      </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="videosViewClick">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="VIDEOS"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/videos_selected_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#427fed"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then your Activity Implementation:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

private View imagesViewSelected;
private View videosViewSelected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ImagesFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    ActionBar.LayoutParams lp1 = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_action_bar, null);

    imagesViewSelected = customNav.findViewById(R.id.images_selected_view);
    videosViewSelected = customNav.findViewById(R.id.videos_selected_view);

    actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp1);
}


public static class ImagesFragment extends Fragment {

    public ImagesFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fragment_locator)).setText("Images Fragment");

        return rootView;
    }
}

public static class VideosFragment extends Fragment {

    public VideosFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fragment_locator)).setText("Videos Fragment");

        return rootView;
    }
}

public void imagesViewClick(View view){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new ImagesFragment())
            .commit();
    imagesViewSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videosViewSelected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void videosViewClick(View view){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new VideosFragment())
            .commit();
    imagesViewSelected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    videosViewSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gabriele Mariotti's [Cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) has a good implementation thereof in the CardView class.

The CardView consists of a [CardHeader which provides an overflow button with a PopupMenuListener, a button to expand/collapse an area, or a customizable button with its listener.](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md)

The [CardHeader](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/HEADER.md)  will greatly assist you in this regard. [CardHeader source code](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/library/src/main/java/it/gmariotti/cardslib/library/internal/CardHeader.java)

HTH