# How to put tabs on the actionBar, same level with Up button and menus

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My application has two tabs and I want to put it right on the ActionBar like this
[image: up button, tabs and menus at the same level]

However these tabs are always separated in lower level compare to Up button and menus as below:

[image: up button, tabs and menus at different levels]

I do not use:

> android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"

How can I achieve my actionbar like the first image?
Thank you very much for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share my final code here, hope this help somebody:

MainActivity.java

```
        package com.example.testfragments;


@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{
    public static String FIRST_TAB_TAG = "first";
    public static String SECOND_TAB_TAG = "second";
    private Button imageTabButton;
    private Button videosTabButton;
    private Fragment imageFragment;
    private Fragment videoFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            imageFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, FirstFragment.class.getName());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, imageFragment)
                    .commit();

        }
        setupTabs();
    }

    @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    { 
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        imageTabButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imagesTabBtn);
        imageTabButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageTabButton.setSelected(true);
        videosTabButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.videosTabBtn);
        videosTabButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return true;
    }


    private void setupTabs() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setLogo(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar_layout);
    }


    /**
     * A placeholder fragment to explore images
     */
    public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

        public FirstFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attachment_galllery_images,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    /**
     * A placeholder fragment to explore videos
     **/
    public static class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

        public SecondFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attachment_galllery_videos,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int viewId = v.getId();
        FragmentTransaction sft;
        switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.imagesTabBtn:
//          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
//            .replace(R.id.container, new FirstFragment())
//            .commit();
            if(!imageTabButton.isSelected()){
                sft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                // Check if the fragment is already initialized
                if (imageFragment == null) {
                    // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                    imageFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, FirstFragment.class.getName());
                    sft.add(R.id.container, imageFragment, FIRST_TAB_TAG);
                } else {
                    // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                    sft.attach(imageFragment);
                }

                if (videoFragment != null) {
                    // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
                    sft.detach(videoFragment);
                }
                sft.commit();


            imageTabButton.setSelected(true);
            videosTabButton.setSelected(false);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.videosTabBtn:
//          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
//            .replace(R.id.container, new SecondFragment())
//            .commit();
            if(!videosTabButton.isSelected()){
                sft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                // Check if the fragment is already initialized
                if (videoFragment == null) {
                    // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                    videoFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, SecondFragment.class.getName());
                    sft.add(R.id.container, videoFragment, SECOND_TAB_TAG);
                } else {
                    // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                    sft.attach(videoFragment);
                }

                if (imageFragment != null) {
                    // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
                    sft.detach(imageFragment);
                }
                sft.commit();

                videosTabButton.setSelected(true);
                imageTabButton.setSelected(false);
            }
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

custom_actionbar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end"
    android:dividerPadding="10dp">




    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/imagesTabBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/abc_tab_indicator_ab_holo"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
        android:text="IMAGES" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/videosTabBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/abc_tab_indicator_ab_holo"
        android:text="VIDEOS" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

By the way, here is the xml of abc_tab_indicator_ab_holo which I found in support library:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_tab_selected_holo" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_list_focused_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_tab_selected_focused_holo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to make a custom layout for your action bar that will have two buttons or Imageviews that look like tabs and switch between fragments onClick(). Just have a popupMenu to reveal the rest of your menu Items.

I have done the layout and the sample Activity implementation:

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="@drawable/action_bar_divider"
    android:dividerPadding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="imagesViewClick">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="IMAGES"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/images_selected_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#427fed"/>
      </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="videosViewClick">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="VIDEOS"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/videos_selected_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#427fed"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the full Activity Implementaion:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

private View imagesViewSelected;
private View videosViewSelected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ImagesFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    ActionBar.LayoutParams lp1 = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_action_bar, null);

    imagesViewSelected = customNav.findViewById(R.id.images_selected_view);
    videosViewSelected = customNav.findViewById(R.id.videos_selected_view);

    actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp1);
}


public static class ImagesFragment extends Fragment {

    public ImagesFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fragment_locator)).setText("Images Fragment");

        return rootView;
    }
}

public static class VideosFragment extends Fragment {

    public VideosFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fragment_locator)).setText("Videos Fragment");

        return rootView;
    }
}

public void imagesViewClick(View view){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new ImagesFragment())
            .commit();
    imagesViewSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videosViewSelected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void videosViewClick(View view){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new VideosFragment())
            .commit();
    imagesViewSelected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    videosViewSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

}

You just have to implement the PopupMenu.

Comment: It sounds good. However I'm not sure we can change fragment by onClick method. Could you give me a suggestion or a link?

Comment: Sorry, I meant on the Buttons' or Imageviews' onClick() method you move from one Fragment to the other. Or rather just switch views.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, I got what you mean. One thing I am still confused is: which view should I use to indicate the tab which has the onSelected method? I think onClick() may not sufficient!